# #include files not found in Apple Open Source software

Tags: xcode, macos, include, include-path

I'm trying to compile Apple's OpenSource software from https://www.opensource.apple.com/ on OS X 10.9.4.

The project includes Xcode project files, but I'm getting some errors due to misplaced include paths.

For example, when trying to compile [`SecurityTool-55115`](https://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/SecurityTool/SecurityTool-55115.tar.gz) from [`os-x-1092`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-1092/) (the latest release up there) on OS X 10.9.4 (the latest production release), I get errors like this:

```
os-x-1092/SecurityTool-55115/cmsutil.c:44:10: fatal error: 'Security/SecCmsBase.h' file not found
#include <Security/SecCmsBase.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

This file, like most others I've seen being reported, is present in the corresponding [`Security-55471.14`](https://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/Security/Security-55471.14.tar.gz) package; I've tried doing some symlinks around, but a lot of errors are still popping up.

What's the proper way to make Xcode work here?

Comment: It seems like doing `OTHER_CFLAGS = -I../Security-55471.14/include/ -I../Security-55471.14/libsecurity_utilities/build/Release/usr/local/include/ -F../Security-55471.14/build/Release/` as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134064/how-to-set-include-path-in-xcode-project/14153027#14153027 seems to fix the include issue, but the project still fails to link in the end: `ld: library not found for -lASN1`

Comment: I think this question needs to be generalized to something like *"How do I compile a framework or program provided at opensource.apple.com"*. I've wondered the same myself when doing things like you are trying to do, and I'd like to see a soup-to-nuts treatment that starts with `wget` and ends with a successful link. If you generalize the question, then I'll toss a 100 point bounty on it.

Comment: It looks like there's a `libasn1` at https://opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_asn1/.

Comment: @jww, feel free to edit to generalise it and add the 100 point bounty. :-)  It kinda sounds like it'd be nice to have some kind of framework that would list all the interdependencies between the different packages from opensource.a.c, kinda similar to MacPorts et al. ^_^