# Install GMP library on Mac OS X 10.9 and Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gmp

My question is as simple as the title. I have a Macbook Pro with OS X Mavericks (10.9.4) and Xcode (5.1.1). I need to install the GMP arbitrary precision libraries so that I can just get to write GMP-enabled programs from within Xcode.

- I downloaded the package from the official website
- I extracted it to my desktop
- `./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-cxx`
- `make`
- `make check`
- `sudo make install`

But when I go to Xcode and just `#include <gmpxx.h>` it doesn't find it. Also adding -lgmp to my linker flags causes an error.

I also tried using homebrew with `brew install gmp` but that didn't work either (same symptohms)

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

You need to ensure that you have an include path `-I/usr/local/include`, before you can include `<gmpxx.h>` (or `<gmp.h>` for that matter).

Also, adding `-lgmp` is insufficient, since that's only the C interface. You want to link with `-lgmpxx` (the C++ library), and possible specify the path to that library with `-L/usr/local/lib`.

You can run `otool -L /usr/local/lib/libgmpxx.dylib`, to ensure that `libgmp.dylib` is already linked to it. Which it should be.

Comment: thanx. this helped. also i checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134064/how-to-set-include-path-in-xcode-project to know how to add include path

Answer (score 1):

Set the *Header Search Path* and *Library Search Path* in the Xcode Project Settings to `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` respectively as, by default, these paths are not searched by Xcode.