# Cannot find file <Python.h>

Tags: python, c++, xcode, macos, python-2.7

I'm using Xcode. I got an error on this new mac:
`'Python.h' file not found.`
At line:
`#include <Python.h>`

When I type `sudo find / -name "Python.h"` in command line, I can see quite a few version of it exist, even inside Xcode.

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5/Python.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5/Python.h
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h`

Anyone have any idea of what is going on? Is that I am not setting up Xcode properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the include path where 'Python.h' exists.

For detailed operation, please refer the question "How to set include path in xcode project" at following URL.

[How to set include path in xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134064/how-to-set-include-path-in-xcode-project)

Comment: The include path in my old project is '/urs/include/python2.7', but it is no longer there in my new mac. I found the right location at '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/' and added it. Thanks.