# #include statement including a different file with same name

Tags: c++, xcode, cocoa

In my Xcode project I added a new target for unit testing (using google C++_ testing framework). I created a new directory (for e.g. /unittest/myproject/) where I copied the source(.h/.cpp) files and did some modification (for e.g. made protected methods to public) for testing purpose and added to unit test target.

But when I Includes a .h files main.cpp it is referring to original file instead of file which is inside /unittest/myproject/. Also I have set the header search path to "$(SRCROOT)/../../unittest/myproject" but still main.cpp refers  to original file (Command+click takes to original file). Can anyone please suggest what I am missing? Xcode Version 4.6.3

Comment: You're gonna want to  temporarily remove the original file from your /usr/local/include or whatever default search path it is in, as those search paths are included before your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set include path in xcode project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134064/how-to-set-include-path-in-xcode-project)

Answer (score 0):

Problematic header is definitely present in another directory, that is seen by XCode as include path.

Such directory may be, for example:

- `/usr/include`
- `/usr/local/include`

and others, depending on your environment settings.

I would suggest you to search for all files with such name and see, what directories will be returned by system.

Then, you should either remove this file[s] (if it is not used anymore) or remove its parent directory from include path set in XCode. That should help.

---

One more thing:

You should also check, what type of include do you use for this file:

- using quotes: `#include "header.h"`
- using brackets: `#include <header.h>`

It's compiler-dependent, but generally, quote-style prioritizes headers, that are present in the same directory as file containing `#include` statement.

From the specification:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `# include <h-char-sequence> new-line`
>
> searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header
>   identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the < and >
>   delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire
>   contents of the header. **How the places are specified or the header
>   identified is implementation-defined.**
>
> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `# include "q-char-sequence" new-line`
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the
>   source file identified by the specified sequence between the "
>   delimiters. The named source file is searched for **in an
>   implementation-defined manner**. If this search is not supported, or
>   if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read
>
> `# include <h-char-sequence> new-line`
>
> with the identical contained sequence (including > characters, if any)
>   from the original directive.