# Xcode throws compile errors in zlib.h

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, zlib, libz

I get a bunch of errors in `zlib.h` about unknown type names, such as `z_const` and `z_crc_t`. Guessing there may be some file (where they are defined) not being included.

Why am I including `zlib.h`? I need to include minizip in my project but it in-turn includes `zlib.h`

zlib version: 1.2.8

Comment: So I noticed what's causing this issue but not sure how to solve it. Those symbols are defined in `zconf.h` and are new in version 1.2.8 but the `#include zconf.h` in `zlib.h` points to the file in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/` and not the one in the same directory as `zlib.h` itself.

Comment: Change your include directories settings so that the one where `zlib` is comes first.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Xcode looks in the sdk directory automatically. Under 'Search Paths', I only see the local directory from where I'm including `zlib.h`

Comment: How about removing the wrong `zlib.h`? (make a copy somewhere so you can restore it if you ever need to)

Comment: Yea that makes it compile, but just seems like a real hack. Another thing is, Xcode complains saying 'Symbol not found' when I right click on `#include "zconf.h` in `zlib.h` even though they are in the same directory and moreover, it compiles!??

Comment: You might find some more information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134064/how-to-set-include-path-in-xcode-project about changing the include paths to make sure you don't have to use hack like this.

Comment: Ok, so made progress. Turned out, I had renamed zlib.h in the sdk directory (at some point) as well. Renamed it back and now Xcode finds `zconf.h` in the local directory. Absurd absurd absurd. Stupid Xcode. Oh well, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, I had renamed `zlib.h` in the SDK directory (at some point) as well. Renamed it back and now Xcode finds `zconf.h` in the local directory. Absurd absurd absurd. Stupid Xcode. Oh well, it works.

[@Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794859/xcode-throws-compile-errors-in-zlib-h?rq=1#comment49643252_30794859)

Answer (score 0):

Change your include directories settings so that the one where zlib is comes first.

Or how about removing the wrong `zlib.h`? Make a copy somewhere so you can restore it if you ever need to.

Or better check: [How to set include path in xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14134064/55075) which is about changing the include paths to make sure you don't have to use hack like this.

[@meneldal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794859/xcode-throws-compile-errors-in-zlib-h/38277150#comment49641654_30794859)