# include GLEW, glfw3 and glm using g++ mac

Tags: c++, g++, glfw, glew, osx-elcapitan

Half a year ago, i was using the libraries glfw3, GLEW and glm to make c++ projects with openGL graphics, and **it did work very well**, but now i can no longer include these libraries.

When things were working fine, i was able to include the three libraries in my c++ files like this:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
```

then i could compile the file from my terminal using this line:

```
g++ in.cpp -o out -lglfw3 -lglew -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo
```

And the result would be working perfectly fine.

I have been working on some not openGL projects for a while, so i'm not sure when exactly it stoped working, but what i do know for sure, is that neither of the libraries can be included know (I have of course tried uninstalling and reinstalling them).

Now however when i try compiling exactly the same way as before the three #include lines produces these errors:

```
fatal error: 'GL/glew.h' file not found
fatal error: 'glfw3.h' file not found
fatal error: 'glm/glm.hpp' file not found
```

Obviously g++ cannot find the libraries, but i have no idea why, and how to fix it (I have of course tried uninstalling and reinstalling them, so i know beyond all doubt, that the libraries are positively installed).
I am suspecting that this has to do with El Capitan

sidenote (**I am not and has never been writing in and compiling from XCode**)

Comment: Most probably your include path is not set properly. Set your include path to openGL library path similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134064/how-to-set-include-path-in-xcode-project

Comment: Adding -l/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1.2 -l/usr/local/Cellar/glew/1.13.0 -l/usr/local/Cellar/glew/1.13.0  to the command that should compile the file does not make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out, that the X-code commandline tools (which i am using even though i am not writing in x-code) had been uninstalled, possibly during the update from Yosemety to El Capitan, i ran this command

```
xcode-select --install
```

And now it seams to be working

Comment: Same here, thank you.