# Header file not found in Xcode 7

Tags: c, xcode, swift2, xcode7, pjsip

I'm creating a framework which embeds some C libraries. The C libraries code is exposed to Swift using a `.modulemap` file. In the `Build Settings` of the target, under `Swift Compiler - Search Paths` section I set path to the `.modulemap` file in `Import Paths` row. Also under `Search Paths` section, paths for libraries and headers are set, in `Library Search Paths` and `Header Search Paths` rows respectively. After adding framework to the app's project and trying to build app, it fails with error `pjsip.h file not found`.

- Values of `Header Search Paths`:

[image]

- Structure of headers folders

[image]

The import process starts with highlighted blue file `pjsua.h` which then imports other headers, those marked with red rectangles.

- The complete list of imported headers in `pjsua.h`

[image]

You can see that imported headers are not living in same folder as `pjsua.h` as should be for successful import, but isn't this the job of the `Header Search Paths` to find the headers ? I don't want to mess the structure of the headers folders, cause it's a third party lib and each time it will be updated each time this 'magic' must be done. The include path is defined in `Other C Flags` row which is same as settings `Header Search Paths`. I'm not sure what I've missed.

**Note:**

1. Headers paths are right.
2. They don't contain any spaces.

P.S [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134064/how-to-set-include-path-in-xcode-project) doesn't help.

**Update:**

This error is showed only when building for Simulator, building for real device Xcode fails with multiple errors `Redefinition of ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is simple but ugly. Set `Header Search Paths` and `Search Paths` for the main project too. That's definitely not the best way to add a framework to a project because it exposes details about framework but it's the only way to fix the problem.

Comment: Oh thank you I spent days to find this solution. It's a total silliness to include the search paths of subproject inside the main project too.