# MathGl for C++ doesn't find file: fatal error

Tags: c++, include, mathgl

Its hours that I'm trying to install mathgl but I'm having a lot of problems.

I tried compiling a simple c++ program just by including *mgl2/mgl.h* but I have errors.

It gives me **fatal error: 'mgl2/mgl.h' file not found**.

I have tried installing it with brew, and also downloading the single folder and placing it inside *usr/local/include* but it still doesn't work.

How can I install it cleanly and without having these errors?

Comment: Installation is one thing, importing the headers is another one. You should configure import paths in XCode.

Comment: Could you explain better how I could do it in XCode?

Comment: take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134064/how-to-set-include-path-in-xcode-project). Also, XCode has a help system built-in.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I have tried using Xcode and adding the search path for the header but it still does to find the file. Maybe I add the wrong path.. if you could explain how I can make it work describing in detail what I have to do I will mark you're answer and upvote it. I really lost the hope, and you would help me a lot with that