# Using ITK with xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, itk

I am working on an xcode project that requires me to use [ITK](https://itk.org/) (a c++ library), I have went through with the installation of ITK, by doing

```
ccmake InsightToolkit-4.13.1
```

and then configuring and generating the files, then runing

```
make
make install
```

but I do not know how to import the library into the xcode project, where I get the following error every time I try building it:

> 'itkImage.h' image file not found

[image]
I would like to know how could I import it and share it with other people on different computers.

Comment: My advice is to use `CMake` to generate your project for your application.

Comment: But I already have a project and I would like to add this library to it

Comment: I understand that. It's just more difficult to do what you want to do. There is information in the itk wiki how to set this up. CMake generates code to setup the factories which you don't get when you don't use it.

Comment: Here is the info: https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/IO/ImageBase/RegisterIOFactories/Documentation.html

Comment: With that said your problem here is a lot more basic. You need to add the include folder for `ITK` to your compiler settings. Also you will have to add libraries to link to your linker settings. I can't tell you how to do that in xcode.

Comment: The thing is I am new to these things and have no experience in them. That is why I am asking, where I am trying to make an osiriX plugin using this library.

Comment: Yes, the thing is I am not sure how to add the include file, but thanks :).

Comment: You will have read the documentation for `xcode`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134064/how-to-set-include-path-in-xcode-project

Answer (score 1):

The `#include` directive comes with two flavors:

- With quotes (`#include "file.h"`)
- With ankle brackets (`#include <file.h>`)

The first usually refers to files relative to your project directory. The second is for system libraries.

You can influence the search path in the project setting:

- double-click on the project in the project explorer
- Click on *Build settings*
- Click on your target
- Click on *All* to view also hidden options
- In the section *Search Paths* you can then update the header search path to include the absolute path of you rlibrary headers.  Attention:  you have to do this for the Debug and for the Release builds:

[image]

This will solve the error that you have reported.

*Remark: be careful, because after this is solved, you could experience some other issues related to the good use of the library, as pointed out by [drescherjm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm) in the comments ([link about registration](https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/IO/ImageBase/RegisterIOFactories/Documentation.html) of custom classes to the library's fatories if Cmake is not used to compile the project)*