# How do I get #include<> to look in a subfolder of the standard system directory?

Tags: c++, header-files

I made the original post below but think the question can be made more general.

I installed a c++ library called ibex. It contains a file ibex.h and a subfolder ibex, and the subfolder contains more header files that are called by ibex.h. Both ibex.h and the subfolder are located in /usr/local/include. I have confirmed this is in my standard system directory.

I'm trying to run the example code from ibex's website below called foo.cpp

```
#include <ibex.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace ibex;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Interval x(0,1);
  cout << "My first interval:" << x << endl;
}
```

but get the error

```
In file included from (filelocationremoved)/foo.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/ibex.h:6:10: fatal error: 'ibex_Setting.h' file not found
```

So basically it can find ibex.h but won't look in the subfolder for ibex_Setting.h (or any of the other files in the subfolder). Is there a way to get it to view all the files in that subfolder as if they are in the /usr/local/include folder without moving them all in?

Thanks!

*Original post:*

I'm a novice c++ user (I mostly use Matlab and a little Python) but need to use c++ for the ibex library (http://www.ibex-lib.org). I'm trying to get their basic example to compile but am having issues. I'm hoping some of the experienced users here can help as I'm making no progress.

Notes:

- Running MacOS Catalina
- Using Sublime text for my IDE
- I have Xcode installed and can run a hello world example
- Installed ibex using: `brew install ibex`

I am trying to run the following example code from their documentation called foo.cpp

```
#include <ibex.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace ibex;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Interval x(0,1);
  cout << "My first interval:" << x << endl;
}
```

but get the error

```
In file included from (filelocationremoved)/foo.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/ibex.h:6:10: fatal error: 'ibex_Setting.h' file not found
```

The ibex_Setting.h file is one of the many files called by ibex.h. I have the ibex.h file located in /usr/local/include and it seems to be able to find it. I also have an alias of the ibex folder (where all the relevant subfiles are located) in the same /usr/local/include folder. But it won't look in that subfolder. That subfolder was created by `brew link ibex`, which I assume is supposed to make it findable. If I move ibex_Setting.h into the /usr/local/include folder, it then finds it, but moves to the next file it can't find (also located in /usr/local/include/ibex). The folder has enough files that I don't want to manually move all of them into /usr/local/include. Also, that would seem silly to need to do that.

In the ibex documentation, it also says to do this:
`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=[prefix]/lib`, where prefix is the folder location. My libibex.dylib is located in /usr/local/lib, which I used. This did not help. I'm sure I'm not providing enough information, but again I'm new to c++ so don't even know what else to include. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamilar with XCode and Sublime Text but I can show you a demo
of the problem, and how to solve it, at the compiler level. You can work how
to apply that in the compiler settings of your IDE.

Here's the contents of a project folder for a program:

```
$ ls -R
.:
header.h  main.cpp  subfolder

./subfolder:
subheader.h
```

And here are the source files and headers:

```
$ cat main.cpp
#include <header.h>

int main()
{
    return foo();
}

$ cat header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <subheader.h>

inline int foo() {
    return bar();
}

#endif

$ cat subfolder/subheader.h 
#ifndef SUBHEADER_H
#define SUBHEADER_H

inline int bar() {
    return 42;
}

#endif
```

I first try to compile `prog` like this:

```
$ g++ -Wall -o prog main.cpp
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: header.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <header.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

which doesn't work because the preprocessor doesn't know where to look
for the *system header* `<header.h>`. (In this context a *system header* just
means a header file specified in `<...>`, as opposed to a *local header*,
that would be specified in `"..."`, and would be searched for in the current
directory when the compiler runs).

I can fix that by adding an `-I dir` preprocessor option, which tells the preprocessor
to search for header files in directory `dir`. Since `header.h` is in the current
directory in this demo, I'll just use `.` as the directory name, rather than
type the full directory name.

```
$ g++ -Wall -I. -o prog main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:
./header.h:4:10: fatal error: subheader.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <subheader.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

That fix has enabled `header.h` to be found, but then in `header.h`, there's
the same sort of problem with `<subheader.h>`.

I fix that in the same way:

```
$ g++ -Wall -I. -I./subfolder -o prog main.cpp
$ ./prog
$ echo $?
42
```

and now everything is OK.

So to a first approximation, what you need to do is make settings in your IDE project to specify
that `-I/usr/local/include` and `-I/usr/local/include/subfolder` are passed to the
compilation command. But in fact you won't need the first one, because `/usr/local/include`
is always a default compiler search directory for header files. The answers to
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14134064/1362568) might help you, though it's old.

Is there any option similar to `-I dir` that will make the preprocessor search *recursively*
in subfolders of `dir` to resolve `#include <...>` directives? No there isn't.

Note that if I'd coded `header.h` with:

```
#include <subfolder/subheader.h>
```

instead of:

```
#include <subheader.h>
```

then I could have compiled my program at the second attempt, `g++ -Wall -I. -o prog main.cpp`.

Well organised packages tend to have their `#include <...>` directives written with
the necessary path elements, like `<subfolder/subheader.h>`, to allow successful compilation
with at most one `-I base/path` option, where `base/path` is the common path prefix for
all the `#include <...>` directives. But some packages don't and there
may be a good rationale for it.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough response! Using the -I/usr/local/include/subfolder command, I was able to get it to find the correct folder. I had to move a few things around in the subfolder because it also had similar issues. But it eventually found everything. Now it's giving me some other errors but these seem package related. So you're answer definitely got me through this issue. Onto the next issue!

Answer (score 0):

/usr/local/include is where ibex.h is there.
Try to add path path of sub directories where ibex_Setting.h is there in Additional include directories. Or if you dont find additional include directories setting, Use ../../../Path to locate your include files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not sure I understand the first suggestion. What do you mean by "In additional include directories"? For the second, ideally, I'd like to not have to do that for every file. My understanding is that the /usr/local/include is one of c++'s default locations, which is why it can find ibex.h. But it doesn't seem to want to find anything in subfolders. I'm not sure if this is just the standard behavior or maybe there is a way for it to see all the files in there as well?

Comment: Actually, after thinking about my question more and your answer, I modified the original question to ask it more directly. Hopefully it makes it clearer.